# Teradata : How to get the server name using query

Tags: teradata

How can I get the server name using query in Teradata?
That is, if I am writing a query on the 'dev' server, it should return the dev server name.

for example, in Sybase : we will be using select @@servername.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like @@servername in TD.
You might create a SQL UDF on each server returning the name, e.g.

```
REPLACE FUNCTION syslib.#servername ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 'dev'
```

If it's created in *syslib* it can be accessed without qualifying it like this:

```
SELECT #servername();
```

Comment: Simple. Convenient. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN LogonSource LIKE '%UAT%'  THEN 'UAT' 
         WHEN LogonSource LIKE '%PROD%' THEN 'Prod' 
         ELSE 'Unknown' 
       END DatabaseName 
FROM   DBC.SessionInfoV 
WHERE  UserName = 'myname';
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you information close to @@servername.

```
select ClientTdHostName, ServerIPAddrByServer, ServerPortByServer 
from DBC.SessionInfo where SessionNo=Session;
```

Validated against 17.xx TD.