Why do I get no results from cursor.execute() and cursor.fetchall() using Python teradatasql driver?
Trying to query a Teradata database from Python using teradatasql, but cursor.execute() and cursor.fetchall() return nothing.  I verified this SQL statement should return a single column of 259 records.
with teradatasql.connect(host='tdp.my-company.org',
                         user=my_login,
                         password=my_password,
                         database=my_schema) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT event.event_number FROM event WHERE event.event_date='2024-01-01'")
        results = cursor.fetchall()


The connection was successful, and cursor.description returns the column name successfully.  But the result set is empty.  What am I missing?

The only explanation is that there are no rows with that event date.

What happens if you try without the WHERE clause?

There are in fact 259 rows with that event date, confirmed by running in Teradata Studio.

Something must be different. Maybe you have a typo in the script. Make sure you're connecting to the same DB. Again, what happens if you leave out the condition?

@Barmar, if I leave out the condition in Teradata Studio, I will retrieve 9M+ records...  If I leave out the condition in this script, I still get an empty results set.   I think I am misunderstanding something about the way teradatasql works.

It's a basic SQL query, I don't think there's anything special to understand. I suspect you're connecting to a different DB than you expect.

Try the query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event in the script.

I am connecting to the same database and running the same query in Teradata Studio and in python.  In Teradata Studio, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event returns a very big number.  From teradatasql, the result is [(0,)].

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982325/teradata-how-to-get-the-server-name-using-query for how you can query the server name. Try that in both places and see if they're the same.

Something has to be different about the connections, nothing else makes sense.
